# Generating HTML file using javascript and using correct MIME types like "text/html"

Tags: javascript, html, file

Currently, I am using this code to create a text file:

```
                    var text = "this is the content";                    
                    var name = "myfilename.txt";
                    var type = "text/plain";
                    var a = document.getElementById("a");
                    a.style.display = "block";
                    var file = new Blob([text], {type: type});
                    a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                    a.download = name;
```

Now, instead of creating a .txt file, if I would like to create a HTML file. I understand, I need to change the "myfilename.html".

What should be the "type" value?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Complete_list_of_MIME_types

Comment: 'text/html' most likely.  you can google mime types for more

Answer (score 0):

```
                var text = "this is the content";                    
                var name = "myfilename.txt";
                var type = "text/html";
                var a = document.getElementById("a");
                a.style.display = "block";
                var file = new Blob([text], {type: type});
                a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                a.download = name;
```